# Wrong PHP script, help me to reduce 28 mysql_queries

Tags: php, mysql

I've ended up with the worst written code in PHP ever (it works, but it is horrible!, maybe you can show me a better way). I am trying to show 14-day statistics on my webpage. I need to show 4 values per day (Files count downloaded, uploaded; File size downloaded and uploaded). What I have is 2 tables (files and downloads_log) and the structure is:

files (file_name, file_size, upload_datetime)
downloads_log (file_name, dl_datetime)

So I need the following:

```
Count all files uploaded from table `files` in specific day
Count all files downloaded from table `downloads_log` in specific day
SUM file_size in table `files` in specific day
SUM file_size in table `files` where files.file_name = downloads_log.file_name in specific day
```

this all I need for last 14 days.

And the "script" that I've already done:

```
  for($i = 13; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $query_downloads  = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT files.file_name, files.file_size, downloads_log.dl_file_name, downloads_log.dl_datetime, COUNT(file_name), SUM(file_size) FROM files, downloads_log WHERE files.file_name = downloads_log.dl_file_name AND `dl_datetime` >= '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i day"))." 00:00:00' AND `dl_datetime` <= '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i day"))." 23:59:59'");
    $result_downloads = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_downloads);

    $query_uploads  = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT file_name, file_size, COUNT(file_name), SUM(file_size) FROM files WHERE `upload_datetime` >= '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i day"))." 00:00:00' AND `upload_datetime` <= '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i day"))." 23:59:59'");
    $result_uploads = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_uploads);
  }
```

Suggest me please, how to achieve this problem with more simple way, to not to give huge load on the mysql, thanks :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My suggestion: Read up on how GROUP BY and using aggregate functions work.

Comment: :DMac updated, :CBroe thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
SELECT files.file_name, files.file_size, downloads_log.dl_file_name, downloads_log.dl_datetime, COUNT(file_name), SUM(file_size) 
FROM files
join downloads_log on files.file_name = downloads_log.dl_file_name and to_days(now())-14<to_days(dl_datetime)
group by to_days(dl_datetime)
```

use the same idea on the other query. You will be fine.

It selects the last 14 days and groups per day.

Comment: Thanks! Previous script was took me 0.0016961097717285 - 0.0018241405487061 seconds and now it takes just 0.0012669563293457, voted as best answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 13;

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT files.file_name, files.file_size, downloads_log.dl_file_name, downloads_log.dl_datetime, DATE(dl_datetime) AS datum, COUNT(file_name), SUM(file_size) FROM files, downloads_log WHERE files.file_name = downloads_log.dl_file_name AND `dl_datetime` >= '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i day"))." 00:00:00' AND `dl_datetime` <= '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i day"))." 23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dl_datetime, '%Y%m%d')");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    $result_downloads[$result['datum']] = $result;

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT file_name, file_size, COUNT(file_name), SUM(file_size), DATE(upload_datetime) AS datum FROM files WHERE `upload_datetime` >= '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i day"))." 00:00:00' AND `upload_datetime` <= '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i day"))." 23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(upload_datetime, '%Y%m%d')");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    $result_uploads[$result['datum']] = $result;
```

This groups the query by different days: `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(upload/dl_datetime, '%Y%m%d')` by creating an unique day-timestamp (%Y = 4 digits Year, %m = 2 digits month, %d = 2 digits day)

The result is filled in an array $result_uploads/downloads with the day as index.